# How to import large csv into mysql table?

Tags: mysql, csv

For smaller csv files, the following has always worked for me...

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/store_emails2.csv' INTO TABLE 
mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Now, I am trying to do this with a file that has 100K rows. Mysql only takes about 50K rows, though. The odd part is that it takes random rows, not just the first 50K. I have no idea what the problem could be, as the file is formatted correctly and I've imported data this way many times. Any ideas as to what may be the problem?

EDIT: including what part of the csv looks like...

```
CUST_NUM,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME,MIDDLE_INIT,PREFIX,SUFFIX,ADDRESS_1,ADDRESS_2,CITY,STATE,ZIP,HOME_TEL,BUS,MAILING,MOD_DATE,SIGN_UP_DATE,BIRTHDAY_DATE,CASHIER,STR,EMAIL

1234556767,name,name,,,,,,,,,9999999999,,Y,6007,607,0101,341,71,email
```

Comment: Any warnings?  "*the file is formatted correctly*" - how can you be so sure?  It would be helpful to see example data from your file... perhaps just include the working row before one that doesn't work, through the one that doesn't work, to the next working row after?  Also, please provide schema for `mytable`.

Comment: It's not that it just stops at a certain row, it takes random rows. for example, it skips the row I posted in the edit, even though it is formatted the same way as every other row. There is no warning, it just tells me that 50k rows have been changed.

Comment: Per my previous comment, could you also include the working rows from before/after the non-working one?  And the schema for `mytable`?